# Azure AD Privileged Identity Management

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

We use Azure AD PIM for azure portal access. I just have "Contributor" permission to my subscription and I had elevated to the subscription. After a day, we received a Sev 3 violation email which states

> AccessMonitoring--[Security Alert] [AlwaysJIT] New persistent '**Owner**' access detected for service, Elevated persistent access that are not in compliance with AlwaysJIT detected for your service

This is the first time that it happened in our team (Elevating to contributor role ended up in **owner** role elevation). why PIM showed unexpected behavior?

Comment: Please try checking the PIM Audit logs (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/privileged-identity-management/azure-pim-resource-rbac#view-activity-and-activations). It might help you to determine what happened.

Comment: I had checked the audit logs in PIM and found that the elevation history is showing as 'Owner'. But I do not have privileges to be elevated to 'Owner' role. So I couldn't understand as to how is it possible to get 'Owner' role without having Owner elevation privileges.

Comment: let me try to check further and get back you.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response - could you please check Audit logs and check the the approver in the Initiated by (actor) column for the "add member to role request approved" event. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/privileged-identity-management/azure-pim-resource-rbac#get-reason-approver-and-ticket-number-for-approval-events)